# SSLError using python requests after trying differents things

Tags: python, ssl, request, ssl-certificate

I'm working on a web scraper. After several successful attempts, I encountered a website that throws the following error when trying to make a GET request.

`requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='<host link>', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: <url> (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1129)')))`

This is the code:

```python
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
from io import BytesIO
import re
from pathlib import Path

from ..pages import get_pages

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent.parent
CERTIFICATE_PATH = str(BASE_DIR / 'searcher/ssl_certificates/bcu.pem')

# Get download link from bcu infractores cheques 
def get_xlxs_download_link_bcu():
    url = get_pages()['bcu_infractores_cheques']['url']
    response = requests.get(url, verify=False) # This is not the best way to handle this
    # response = requests.get(url, verify=CERTIFICATE_PATH) # Another try
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

    p_tag = soup.find('p')
    print(p_tag)

    # Download a tag contains and contains .xlsx string in href
    download_link = p_tag.find('a', href=lambda href: href and '.xls' in href)
    return url + download_link['href']

def scrap_from_bcu_infractores_cheques(name):
    xlxs_url = get_xlxs_download_link_bcu()
    # Download .xlxs file
    response = requests.get(xlxs_url, verify=False) # This is not the best way to handle this
    # response = requests.get(url, verify=CERTIFICATE_PATH) # Another try
    if response.status_code == 200:
        with BytesIO(response.content) as bce:
            # From the 10th row
            df = pd.read_excel(bce, skiprows=9)
            # Verify if name is in the second column
            matches = []
            for index, row in df.iterrows():
                if isinstance(row.iloc[1], str) and re.search(re.escape(name), row.iloc[1], re.IGNORECASE):
                    matches.append(row.tolist())
            
            # Join first 3 columns in matches using | as separator
            matches = [' | '.join(map(str, match[:3])) for match in matches]
            return (matches != [], df.columns.tolist(), matches, xlxs_url)
    else:
        print("Error downloading the file.")
        return []
```

I tried some things like putting `verify=False` (insecure) or downloadig the .pem file from the page, adding it to the `site-packages/certifi/cacert.pem` path and setting `verify=path/to/page_cert.pem` but still don't working.

Note: in 'bcu.pem' I have the CA cert, downloaded from the page. That one with the `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` at the start. I added the same certificate in the `certifi/cacert.pem` file

The link I want to scrap is this:
[BCU Infractores de Cheques](https://www.bcu.gub.uy/Servicios-Financieros-SSF/Paginas/Infractores-a-la-ley-de-cheques.aspx)

Thanks for you time.

Comment: *".... but still don't working."* - These are unfortunately too few details. You need to provide real code which shows the problem and your attempts to solve it. And since it is specific to a site better include the real URL you want to access.  See also [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Hi Steffen, hope this edit helps to understand better my problem. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: The server is misconfigured, it has missing chain certificates - see https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=www.bcu.gub.uy. You cannot use the server certificate itself as trusted CA cert in `verify`, since it is not a CA certificate. Instead you need to use the missing chain, i.e. combine the certificates mentioned in the SSLLabs report. You can export all three (chain +root) from the certificate dialog in the browser.